# Torsion of modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

Given a left module $M$ over a domain $R$, I am interested in irreducible elements $r\in R$ such that $r\cdot m=0$ for some $m\in M-\{0\}.$ I think "torsors" would be perfect name for such $r$'s (despite of another meaning assigned to this term already), but perhaps there is a name for them in the literature?

More importantly, did anyone study the sets $T_M$ of all such torsors for given finitely generated $M$? Obviously, $T_M$ is finite for a PID, like $R=\mathbb C[x].$ But what can be said about $T_M$ for finitely generated $\mathbb C[x,y]$-modules $M$?

Comment: There's the related notion of "associated ideal", with indeed finiteness properties (for a f.g. module over a noetherian commutative ring, the set of associated ideals is finite).

Comment: Why not "zero divisors relative to $M$", or some variant?

Answer (score 4):

These are called zero-divisors on the module, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor) for instance. You ask for irreducible zero divisors, to be precise. The ring can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

In general, as Martin said, these are called *zero divisors on $M$*.

If you fix an element of $M$, they are also called *annihilators* of the element:
For an $m\in M$, the set of elements in $R$ that annihilate it, i.e., the set of *annihilators* of $m$ is called (not surprisingly) the (left) annihilator ideal of $m$. And, yes, it is a (left) ideal. In fact it is the kernel of the natural morphism $R\to M$ induced by $1\mapsto m$. The intersection of all the annihilator ideals form the annihilator ideal of $M$:
${\rm Ann_R(M)}:=\{r\in R| rm=0, \forall m\in M\}$. This is actually a two-sided ideal even if $R$ is non-commutative.

**Caveat** the following was written without the assumption that $r\in R$ should be irreducible. So it doesn't entirely match up with the OP's intention, but perhaps it is still useful. See also the comments.

The set you are proposing, $T_M$ is the union of all of these annihilator ideals and because of that it is usually not an ideal (or even a subgroup). However, for instance, if $R$ is a commutative ring and $R=M$, then the set of zero divisors is exactly the union of the associated prime ideals, so that's something. Also, the complement of $T_M$ is always a multiplicative monoid, because if $a$ and $b$ are non-zero-divisors on $M$ (which is also called to be *regular on $M$*), then so is $ab$. This actually implies that if $T_M$ is an ideal of $R$, then it is actually a prime ideal.

Finally, I am not sure what you mean by $T_M$ being finite. If $R=\mathbb C[x]$ and $M=\mathbb C[x]/J$ for any ideal $J\subseteq \mathbb C[x]$, then every element of $J$ is a zero divisor on $M$. So, unless $J=0$, $T_M$ is an infinite set.

Comment: $T_M$ is finite for finitely generated $M$ over a PID, because $T_M$ consists of irreducible "zero divisors" of $M$. I get what you say (though none of your statements about $T_M$ is exactly correct). My intention was to get some more advanced results about $T_M$, like in the example I brought of $R=\mathbb C[x,y]$. The terminology is helpful. But the most helpful was the comment by @YCor about associated ideals technology, which helps in actual computing of $T_M.$

Comment: Right. I missed your assumption about r having to be irreducible. That's a tricky assumption in rings that are not UFDs. And even for $R=\mathbb C[x,y]$, if you take for example $M=R/(x,y)$, then $T_M$ contains $ax+by$ for every $a,b\in\mathbb C$, so it is infinite. My guess is that this will only be finite for PIDs.